# populate images from picture library to ListView in Windows 10 App

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-store-apps, uwp

i am trying to show all images from default picture library to ListView in windows app but i am only able to show the names of images not the all images from the folder, here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.Storage;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234238

namespace ListView
{
/// <summary>
/// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
/// </summary>
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        showall();
    }

    public async void showall()
    {
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> file = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFilesAsync();

        foreach (StorageFile file1 in file)
        {
            list.Items.Add(file1.Name);
        }

    }
```

here is the xaml code...

```
<Page
x:Class="ListView.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ListView"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="350" Height="350">
            <ListView Width="300" Height="300" Name="list" SelectionChanged="list_SelectionChanged">
                <Image Width="200" Height="200" Name="img"></Image>
            </ListView>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top">

            <Image Width="300" Height="300" Name="img1" />
            <TextBlock Width="300" Height="30" Name="txt1" />

        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>


</Grid>
```

Comment: here is image link of listView Design: http://prntscr.com/djhu3f

Comment: So what is the problem? Where is your xaml for Binding this?

Comment: @AVKNaidu EdITED Check Above

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatic conversion from StorageFile names to images.

You'll need two things, first a DataTemplate with an Image control in your ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="list">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Second, BitmapImages created from the StorageFiles, which are added to the Items collection instead of the file names:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    Loaded += OnLoaded;
}

private async void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    list.Items.Clear();

    var files = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFilesAsync();

    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();

        using (var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(stream);
        }

        list.Items.Add(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Note also that loading is done in a `Loaded` event handler instead of directly calling an async method without awaiting it. Event handlers are the only methods that can safely be `async void` and not be awaited.

Comment: it's loading every picture 2 times and how to set pixel for these pictures?

Comment: The Loaded handler was probably called twice (no idea why). I've changed it so that it initially clears the list. Besides that, how to set pixel data is a completely different question. Please don't ask follow-up questions in comments. Ask a new question on StackOverflow instead.

Answer (score 0):

While Clemens' approach will work for you, I would like to show you a different approach. Using ViewModels.

Here is a PicturesViewModel:

```
public class PicturesViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<ImageSource> MyImages { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<ImageSource>();

    public async Task GetImages()
    {
        var files = await KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary.GetFilesAsync();
        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            using (var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
            {
                BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                await image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
                MyImages.Add(image);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usually if it is a synchronous activity, you can write your logic in constructor. Since this is asynchronous, i am using another method in my view model to load a `List` of `BitmapImage`s

Now in your `MainPage_Loaded` (a handler method of the MainPage's `Loaded` event as shown in the other answer) you need to do this:

```
private async void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var viewModel = new PicturesViewModel();
    DataContext = viewModel;

    await viewModel.GetImages();
}
```

And your ListView is just `Binding`

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyImages}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: Fixed XAML and changed the view model to use widely accepted naming conventions for property names. Also the code comment about the DataContext was wrong. The ListView inherits the DataContext from the Page, so it doesn't matter if you set `list.DataContext` or `this.DataContext`. The latter is better because other elements in the Page could bind to the same view model. Also, returning the view model instance from the GetImages() method didn't make sense.

Comment: It's also not strictly required to instantiate the view model in the Loaded handler. You could as well do that in the MainPage constructor. The important thing is to call the async GetImages() method in the Loaded handler.

Comment: And while we're on it, doing improvements, I also changed the MyImages collection to be read-only, and changed the element type to ImageSource, a base class of BitmapImage, which provides greater flexibility in the number of bitmap types you could pass to the collection, e.g. WriteableBitmap instead of BitmapImage.